# What is this spiky-leaved plant with short lived yellow flowers?

Tags: identification

I found this growing in one of my pots.

[image: mystery flower]

Does anyone know what it is? I think it might be a wild flower. The flowers only come out for one day and are replaced by another from the same stalk.

Comment: I have brought the picture inline, improved your title, and so on. Can you please edit to include some information about your location?

Comment: How tall is it? It looks a bit like yellow eyed grass.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed - definitely looks like a [Sisrynchium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyrinchium). Possibly Sisyrinchium californicum, although the petals on yours are more rounded than in the pictures of that variety that I've seen.  Sisrynchium are actually relatives of the iris, and can spread and naturalize well in many circumstances.  There is also a blue version, which is probably better known in the US than the yellow types.

Comment: Many thanks I thought it was a grass have found it in my book .